# Why is others when trying to login via fb in your web not having same permission?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

in my login_url i state the scopes so that i can get the information of a user like location and email. But when others try to login via fb the results has only the users id and name

```
$this->facebook->login_url('login2/fb_login',array('scope' => 'email,user_photos,user_location'));
```

in my request

```
$this->facebook->request('get', '/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email,location');
```

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Read about Login Review: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review

Most permissions need to get reviewed before you can go public with them.